# Media not playing in <video> and <audio>

Tags: html, audio, video, browser, codec

I am saving video and audio to my AWS cloud storage.

- Video (.mp4 format)
- Audio (.m4a format)

When I insert the tags in the HTML:

```html
<video controls>
  <source type="video/mp4" src="https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/hikebeat/video/hikebeat_56e997a92176868d8b3ef8c5_1458247689.mp4">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

<audio controls>
  <source type="audio/mp4" src="https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/hikebeat/audio/hikebeat_56e997a92176868d8b3ef8c5_1458245562.m4a">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

The result is that **only the audio** plays in the browser, the video does not work. However, when trying to manually download the video, it is perfectly playable in media software.

Is there something I am overlooking when working with the `<video>` and `<audio>` HTML5 elements?

Comment: There is some problem with your video, its not accessible ! Did you check the format correctly ?

Comment: When you visit AWS, you can right-click and download the video.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Your video file is corrupt</strike>

Please see: https://gyazo.com/9631bad0402d8b3870fd4aee0b84fe52

**Edit**

It appears to actually be something to do with the way S3 is serving the file. I rehosted the file on my own server and tried it with no issue.

**Edit Again**

It's the gzip encoding. It seems browsers don't like playing video which has been transferred compressed.

Comment: I don't think the video is corrupt; it's more likely a different file type than the extension says it is. When I try the OP's snippet, it works fine when I remove the `type` attribute from the `source`.

Comment: I've checked the video itself and it's H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part 10) which should play fine on all browsers. But there's something wrong with the file which is tripping mine up, at least.

Comment: I see that it only works (with the file from the original AWS site) in Mozilla when I remove the `type="video/mp4"`. Not in Chromium. Oh well.